# Why Tortoise SVN does not show Commit option on some folders on local machine?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This might be a silly question. I have started to use Tortoise SVN since last month. I checked out a few folders from repository and they are fine. When I right click on them, I can see commit, check out and other options too...

But, I wanted to push something to the repo. I could not see a commit option, so I played with it, googled and did an import. The folder was pushed into the repo. Now, for all folders I checked out from repo, I can see a red exclamation or right tick mark. But this one which I pushed has no indication like that. Also, there is no option called commit when I right click on it. 
Why is it? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Import" does not actually create a working copy. "Import" only adds the files in the specified directory, to a location in the repository. It does NOT convert the specified directory to a working copy or associate it in any way with the repository server.

Right now, your best option is to `svn checkout` the imported directory to a new location and move over any modified files from the directory you did the import from.

To avoid the problem in the future, instead of doing "import", try creating a new directory on the repository, then making a `svn checkout` of that empty directory to get a working copy, then `svn add` any files you want into that empty directory, then `svn commit` them.

Answer (score 3):

Is your directory added to SVN? (It should be, if the import worked)

When you right click on the directory and select properties, do you see a "Subversion" tab?

You can also check the SVN log, to see if there is a commit from when you imported the files 
(import = add+commit)

If you cant see a commit of the files that you want to push, you can add and commit them.

Answer (score 1):

For a sync folder, I forgot to copy over the hidden ".svn" folder to the root directory when moving folders to the sync. Once I did, all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have set the options/properties.

Navigation: **`TortoiseSVN-->General-->ContextMenu`**

Here you find a option  ***"Donot show context menu for following path"..***

You need to clear all paths, so that u can commit the code.

*Second option is you can still commit the code from it's parent directory.*

Answer (score 0):

If you cant see any SVN operations on the Folder.. Please verify below step

Check whether your workspace has **.svn** folder, which is hidden folder. *.svn* folder plays a major role in committing your changes to server

To View Hidden folder Go To Organize-->Folder Options --> View --> Show hidden files, folders...

If you cant find .svn folder, then u might have exported the code from server, which you cannot commit any files..